# Select dividing of two time series

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have first query:

```
WITH one_day_intervals AS (
  SELECT date_trunc('day', (current_date-offs-2)) AS start_time,
         date_trunc('day', (current_date-offs-1)) AS end_time
  FROM generate_series(1, 7, 1) AS offs
)
SELECT start_time, end_time, x
FROM (
  SELECT i.start_time AS start_time, i.end_time AS end_time, count(*) AS x
  FROM (
    SELECT created
    FROM tracking_msg AS tm
    WHERE tm.cid='ae69123c-cb29-420b-9a65-bbe6ae156f57' AND tm.sid NOT IN (SELECT sid FROM session_msg)
  ) AS sub1
  RIGHT JOIN one_day_intervals AS i ON sub1.created >= i.start_time AND sub1.created < i.end_time
  GROUP BY i.start_time, i.end_time ORDER BY i.start_time
) AS sub2;
```

and at the output:
[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1W7Wy.png) 
And second query:

```
WITH one_day_intervals AS (
  SELECT date_trunc('day', (current_date-offs-2)) AS start_time,
         date_trunc('day', (current_date-offs-1)) AS end_time
  FROM generate_series(1, 7, 1) AS offs
)
SELECT start_time, end_time, y
FROM (
  SELECT i.start_time AS start_time, i.end_time AS end_time, count(*) AS y
  FROM (
    SELECT created
    FROM tracking_msg AS tm
    WHERE tm.cid='ae69123c-cb29-420b-9a65-bbe6ae156f57' AND tm.sid IN (SELECT sid FROM session_msg)
  ) AS sub1
  RIGHT JOIN one_day_intervals AS i ON sub1.created >= i.start_time AND sub1.created < i.end_time
  GROUP BY i.start_time, i.end_time ORDER BY i.start_time
) AS sub2;
```

Output: [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t31Oy.png)

Each query have the same date period. I want to select start_time, end_time and x/y

Comment: I tried to fix to the formatting of the SQL, but the SO interface then claims _my_ post has too much code.

Answer (score 0):

So, basically the difference between `x` and `y` is that `tm.sid` is `IN` / `NOT IN` another table.

You can calculate both at once, with [conditional aggregation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES):

```
SELECT ...,
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE tm.sid NOT IN (SELECT sid FROM session_msg)) AS x,
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE tm.sid IN     (SELECT sid FROM session_msg)) AS y
```

Or, with older PostgreSQL (9.3 or before):

```
SELECT ...,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN tm.sid NOT IN (SELECT sid FROM session_msg) THEN 1 END) AS x,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN tm.sid IN     (SELECT sid FROM session_msg) THEN 1 END) AS y
```

Comment: I don't understand how I should use it in my query.  Can you explain?

Comment: @PetroProkopovych instead of `COUNT(*)`. And you don't need 2 separate query, you can use only one (which does not filter `tm.sid` in the `WHERE` clause with `tm.sid [NOT] IN (...)`)

Comment: But it's not working, becouse I use tm.sid before I define tm